# How can I avoid "parse" validation error for custom angularjs directive when setting model to undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive for a date input field that uses `$formatters` and `$parsers` to modify the model and view value.

Whenever I clear the input field I want to set the model value to `undefined`.  This is done by returning `undefined` from the $parsers function. The problem is that when `invalid` is returned from a $parsers function the input will get invalid:

```
$error":{"parse":true},
```

Is there some way to set the model value to `undefined` without making it invalid?

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guspersson/vnk9m1wj/)

**Edit:**

The only solution I've come up with so far is setting a timeout before returning **undefined** from the $parser function:

```
$timeout(function(){
    ngModel.$setValidity('parse', true);
}, 0);
return undefined;
```

This feels like a hack however.

Comment: Are using some custom component?

Comment: Yes, we have created our own custom directive for a date input field.

Comment: Sorry, pal, I'm trying to help you but the battery on my crystal ball just died and I forgot the charger at home. Can you give more specifics (or better yet, link to a jsfiddle)? Are your custom directive just wrapping a widget from some popular toolkit?

Comment: @PauloScardine I've now added an example on jsfiddle.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the update! I recommend you return `null` instead of `undefined`, because undefined is ambiguous. The value `null` really means "no data". If this solution is acceptable I can turn it into a full answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure however that null will work in my case, since other parts of the code depend on an empty input being set to undefined.

Answer (score 0):

As Paulo points out above, if it works for your situation, returning `null` (or some comparable blank value that's not undefined) is probably your best bet.

Unfortunately, it seems that returning `undefined` will definitely cause the $parsers pipeline to stop and force an error state.

Your $timeout definitely does feel like a hack, but if you REALLY have to return undefined, it's probably the only way.